# How to get a folder in eclipse to refresh its content or use external folder

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, directory, file-handling

I wanted to use an external folder because in my last project that i lost i used an external folder and every time i changed something to my tiled map and ran my program the changes would be there. However, now that I'm using an assets folder within my project, it works but I have to delete the whole folder go to its actual location and recopy the folder back in in order for changes to be seen. I have tried refreshing both the folder and the project numerous times but it seems to force me to have to delete it and recopy the folder back in. If someone could tell me how to either use an external folder or get my folder to refresh like how I said it used to I would be very grateful

Comment: Use an external folder for *what* exactly?  For Java source code?  For data files?  This question is nearly impossible to understand.  Can you rewrite to describe the reproduce-by steps?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the folder name in the Package Explorer and press F5. That refreshes all the resources in that directory!